# Why doesn't Gmail show embedded images? It works on iPhone's Mail app

Tags: gmail, images, attachment

I'm using Google Apps and sending/receiving mail with other users inside this domain.

I'm receiving messages with inline images (posted in the middle of sentences) but these **inline images are not displayed in Gmail** -- neither in the message body between the words where they should be, nor as attachments.

The same mail displays correctly in the standard Mail app on my iPhone -- see this comparison:

Here are the images, highlighted in green, and visible on iPhone:

> [image: iPhone Mail screenshot]

The same images are not shown in Gmail, and they also don't appear as attachments:

> [image: Gmail screenshot]

It looks like a problem with Gmail, and it's not limited to this particular message. How can I fix this?

---

**Update:** Looking at the original message content (see full in [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/qkayGMDa)) it appears that the images are inline in a multipart message, and Gmail is choosing the part without the inline images -- see excerpt below. Both sender and receiver are using Gmail (Google Apps edition) and neither one of us is seeing a message about "display hidden images".

```
To: Torben Gundtofte-Bruun <torben@g-b.dk>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=90e6ba3fd5f3614bcd04abf2416d
--90e6ba3fd5f3614bcd04abf2416d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Hvad kan "Save thing <<Thing Stack>> onto <Thing Stack>" bruges til?

Jeg ville tro at den l=C3=A6gger hele stakkens indhold i stakken igen, men =
den
l=C3=A6gger blot "" i stakken -- men man kan ikke "Compare thing with" med =
"" som
argument, s=C3=A5 jeg undrer mig lidt. Der m=C3=A5 v=C3=A6re en use case! >=
;-]

--90e6ba3fd5f3614bcd04abf2416d
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hvad kan &quot;Save thing &lt;&lt;Thing Stack&gt;&gt; onto &lt;Thing Stack&=
gt;&quot; bruges til?<br><img src=3D"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN=
SUhEUgAAAR8AAABuCAIAAACRPIDKAAAGOUlEQVR4nO2dzbmkKhBADW1iMoKXh5kYwSxnYRQmwVu=
```

Comment: Does it put the image as an attachment?

Comment: @Fogest: No, in Gmail the message appears incomplete. No images anywhere.

Comment: How was the email created? In Gmail? What is the image format? And is anyone getting the "Display images from ....." link?

Comment: No solution to this yet? GMail seems to randomly decide when inline images will work and when not for me. This has been like that for YEARS now. The feature is there, but I simply can't rely on it. Do they even care about this? Doesn't look like it.

Comment: @n2liquid: I think you're right, they aren't going to fix this.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun: It's *so easy* to mistakenly use this broken feature. They should remove it. I'm tired of talking to invisible things and look stupid.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable the `Inserting Images` Lab.

*I don't have an email client set up to test receiving inline images, but sending an inline image from another account with it enabled works fine.*

Source: http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/04/new-in-labs-inserting-images.html

Comment: I just checked - that Lab is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did and it worked.

1. Delete the "3D" after "=". I'm not fluent enough to know why this happened, but the line: "img src=**3D**"data:image/png;base64,iVBO..." should read "img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBO...."
2. Get rid of the "=" at the end of each line
3. Save the file as *.htm and open it with chrome
4. The images should appear. If it's not appearing, add this red dot from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

> img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
>   AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
>   9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot"

and if that doesn't appear you have bigger problems.

Comment: `=3D` is escape text of `=` because the content of email (HTML) has to be escaped, as part of attachment inside email.  Email was originally plain text and always in plain text.  HTML email is, indeed, an attachment with escaped text.

Comment: I want to mentioned this because this answer lead me to the wrong direction and I spent an hour on the `3D`, until I released it is not `3D` but `=3D`.